# How to pass an expression in thymleaf fragment param?

Tags: java, thymeleaf

I am trying to display a thymleaf page, but I got multiple errors while I implemented different solution.

I have the following fragment:

```
<div th:fragment="documentField(field, fieldLabel, isMandatory)">
```

So I tried the following code to display this fragment:

```
<div th:replace="fragments/document.html 
    :: documentField(field='Certification', 
        fieldLabel='CERTIFICATION_PROCEDURE', 
        isMandatory='(${#boolsIsTrue(#session.getAttribute('isCertificate'))}')">
</div>
```

I got this error:

```
Caused by: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Could not parse as expression: "~{fragments/document.html 
    :: documentField(field='Certification', 
        fieldLabel='CERTIFICATION_PROCEDURE', 
        isMandatory='(${#boolsIsTrue(#session.getAttribute('isCertificate'))}')}" (template: "application/certification-documents" - line 47, col 8)
```

I tried the parameter `isMandatory` without using `#boolsIsTrue`, and also declaring a variable for `#session.getAttribute('isCertificate'))` without success.

`isCertificate` attribute is passed as boolean.

Do you have any idea how to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass `true` or `false` as the value for your `isMandatory` parameter, you can use this:

```
isMandatory=${#session.getAttribute('isCertificate')}
```

Don't use an enclosing set of apostrophes, or the parentheses `'(...)'`. Those are not needed here. The `#boolsIsTrue()` function is also not needed - it serves a different purpose (similar to `th:if`).

The revised div:

```
<div th:replace="fragments/document.html 
    :: documentField(field='Certification', 
        fieldLabel='CERTIFICATION_PROCEDURE', 
        isMandatory=${#session.getAttribute('isCertificate')})">
</div>
```

Comment: Indeed, it was because of parentheses so it considered it as a String. It works now. Thnx